# Create folder and upload file at the same time

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, mkdir

I'm experiencing a problem in my code. I know that i'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.
I have a photo upload form and it have to create a folder if it doesn't exist already, and upload the picture to that folder.

So my problem is that **I can't do both at the same tim**e.
If the folder already exist the image is uploaded, but if the folder don't exist, it only create the folder and I have to do another upload for that picture goes into that folder.

Here is my code.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="input-image-3" class="file-loading" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</form>

        <script>
        $("#input-image-3").fileinput({
            uploadUrl: "upload.php",
            allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg","jpeg", "png", "gif"],
            maxImageWidth: 100,
            maxImageHeight: 100,
            resizePreference: 'height',
            maxFileCount: 10,
            resizeImage: true,


        }).on('filepreupload', function() {
            $('#kv-success-box').html('');
        }).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
            $('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
            $('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
        });

        </script>
```

**UPLOAD.PHP**

```
<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "up/test/"; // Upload directory, later i'll get the name of user
$filename=$file['filename'];
$extension = '.jpg';
$i=1;
while(file_exists($path.$filename.$extension)){
                  $filename=$file['filename']."teste_($i)";
                 $i++;}

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) { 
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files

                    if(!is_dir($path)){mkdir($path, 0755);} // If dont exist, create folder

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$filename.$extension);    
            }    
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode (json_decode ("{}"));
?>
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try $oldumask = umask(0); mkdir($path, 0777,TRUE); umask($oldumask); I use this trick

Comment: Hello, @SameerJain. Thank you for your help, I've tried to add that code, but unfortunately that doesn't work too. It just keeps doing one action at the time.

Answer (score 6):

Try this bellow code for upload files in new created directory.

```
<?php
    define("SITE_NAME","project_name/"); //constant for project name
    define("SITE_PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".SITE_NAME); //constant for project base directory
    define("IMAGES_URL",SITE_URL."images/"); //constant for image directory


    $upload_base_dir=IMAGES_URL;
    $upload_time_dir=date('Y')."/".date('m')."/".date('d')."/"; // setup directory name
    $upload_dir = $upload_base_dir.$upload_time_dir;

    if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);  //create directory if not exist
    }

    $image_name=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image=time().'_'.$image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$upload_dir.$image); // upload file
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if(!is_dir($path)){mkdir($path, 0755);
Change it to 777 and check if it helps
or try this out

```
>     if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) && $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] != "")
>         {
>             $target_dir = "/pics/";
>             $target_file = 'Image_'.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
>     
>             $uploadOk = 1;
>             $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
>     
>         // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
>             $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
>     
>             if ($check !== false) {
>                 $msg['status'] = '1';
>                 $msg['message'] = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
>                 $uploadOk = 1;
>             } else {
>                 $msg['status'] = '0';
>                 $msg['message'] = "File is not an image.";
>                 $uploadOk = 0;
>             }
>     
>         // Check if file already exists
>             if (file_exists($target_file)) {
>                 $msg['status'] = '0';
>                 $msg['message'] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
>                 $uploadOk = 0;
>             }
>         // Check file size
>             if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
>                 $msg['status'] = '0';
>                 $msg['message'] = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
>                 $uploadOk = 0;
>             }
>         // Allow certain file formats
>             if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
>                 $msg['status'] = '0';
>                 $msg['message'] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
>                 $uploadOk = 0;
>             }
>     
>         // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
>             if ($uploadOk == 0) {
>                 $msg['uploadstatus'] = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
>         // if everything is ok, try to upload file
>             } else {
>                 $target_dir = "/pics/";
>                 if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
>                     try {
>                         mkdir($target_dir);
>                     } catch (Exception $ex) {
>                         die("error");
>                     }
>                 }
>                 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
> $target_dir.$target_file)) {
>                     $data['imageTitle'] = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
>                     $data['imageLink'] = $target_file;
>                     $data['memberId'] = 5;     
>                         $msg['id'] = 5;
>                         $msg['name'] = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
>                         $msg['size'] = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . "kb";
>                         $msg['status'] = '1';
>                         $msg['message'] = "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
>                         $msg['uploadstatus'] = "file uploaded";
>                         $msg['imagepath'] = $target_dir;
>                   
>                 } else {
>                     $msg['status'] = '0';
>                     $msg['message'] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
>                     $msg['uploadstatus'] = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
>                 }
>     
>             }
>         }
```

Comment: Dear @RishikRohan, I've tried both of your solutions, but unfortunately neither of them work for me. Your code output two errors. But i'll not discard it yet, i'll try to make it work. Thank you